# COUNT rows of sql query involving SELECT specific rows+FROM+WHERE+AND

Tags: mysql, count

How do I return the count of rows returned by this query instead of query results:

```
SELECT collections.name, collections.description, collections.collection_id, collections.name, collections.description, collections.date, users.name
FROM users, collections
WHERE collections.user_id = users.user_id
AND (
collections.description LIKE  "%%searchTerm%%"
OR collections.name LIKE  "%%searchTerm%%"
OR users.name LIKE  "%%searchTerm%%"
)
AND (
reported = false
OR (
reviewed = true
AND approved = true
)
)
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do use count(1) or count(collections.collection_id)

```
SELECT 
    count(collections.collection_id)
FROM 
    users,
    collections
WHERE 
    collections.user_id = users.user_id
    AND (
            collections.description LIKE  "%%searchTerm%%"
            OR collections.name LIKE  "%%searchTerm%%"
            OR users.name LIKE  "%%searchTerm%%"
        )
    AND (
        reported = false
        OR (
            reviewed = true
            AND approved = true
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways, you could

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM...
```

which will return the count at the expense of the actual data, or you can use a function in whichever language you're using to query the database to check how many rows there are.

Comment: good point about perhaps doing the counting back in the language that made the mysql request (PHP in this case). I should reconsider what I am doing because I actually do go and redo the query again with a limit. This initial query is to calculate the number of pages in a pagination script.

Answer (score 0):

See also FOUND_ROWS() along with SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

It might perform better than doing one query with a COUNT(*) and another to get the data.

ie can run one query to get the results - and at the same time get a count. (ok, you do still use two queries, but the second is cheap, its just fetching the calculated total)